# How to untar *.tar.bz2 using tcl in windows

Tags: tcl

Is there any TCL package to untar .tar.bz2 files?
I tried TCL **tar** library but I could not able to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't trivial. You'll need something to decompress the tar.bz2 file — I've found some source code at http://download.gna.org/bztcl/0.6/ but I can't verify that it will work easily for you on Windows — and you can then use the tar library that you've already found. The bztcl build apparently needs tclmore too — see http://download.gna.org/tclmore/0.7/ — and you'll need to have a C compiler available, and probably a build of the bzip2 library too.

Due to the complex nature of the bzip2 compression format, I don't think there's ever been anyone who's written a pure Tcl decompressor for it.